# Do vampiric champions gain health from absorbed damage?

Tags: diablo-iii

I recently fought a pack of Vampiric Desecrators, and hit [Serenity](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/active/serenity) while standing in the desecration to finish off one of the mobs that was at low life. Almost instantly, the other two mobs were at full health again. I'm *think* they were lower on health, but I'm not sure.

Has anyone seen anything like this or done some testing?

**Does damage you absorb still heal vampiric champions?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absorbed damage should not heal vampiric champions. I just tested this on Hell with my Wizard and the skill "Diamond Skin" - whenever this skill was active and one of the champions swung at me, they gained no health. I am unsure if it is any different for Monks or their skills, but I doubt it.